# Extra 32 bytes of local memory allocated for OpenCL Kernel

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I'd like to figure out why I'm receiving the following error for an OpenCL kernel that I'm trying to run:

```
Context error: [CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES] :
OpenCL Error : clEnqueueNDRangeKernel failed: local memory usage (16416 bytes) is more than available on the device (16384 bytes)
```

The kernel is defined as:

```
__kernel void kernelFun(__read_only image2d_t src,
                        __global __write_only uchar8 *dst,
                        __global uchar4 *endpointBuffer,
                        __local uchar4 *pixelBuffer)
{
  ...
}
```

And I'm allocating the local memory using the standard `clSetKernelArg` routine:

```
clSetKernelArg(gKernel, 3, kPixelBufferBytes, NULL);
```

where `kPixelBufferBytes` is equal to 16384.

My question is, where are these extra 32 bytes coming from?

Comment: By the way, the `__write_only` and `__read_only` attributes are for image objects only, and don't have any meaning for buffers. It's strange that implementations don't throw an error or warning for this. You specify write-only/read-only info for buffers when you create the buffer on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some OpenCL implementations are known to store kernel arguments using the same physical memory that is used for local memory. You have 32 bytes worth of kernel arguments, which would explain where this discrepancy is coming from.

For example, NVIDIA GPUs definitely used to do this (see page 25 of [NVIDIA's original OpenCL best practices guide](http://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/CUDABrowser/downloads/papers/NVIDIA_OpenCL_BestPracticesGuide.pdf)).

Comment: This implies pointers are 8 bytes each? Could this be because I'm using a 64-bit OS?

Comment: @Mokosha Yes, I assumed 64-bit hardware. You can check whether your OpenCL device is 32 or 64 bits by calling `clGetDeviceInfo` with the `CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS` argument.

Comment: The return value for `CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS` gives 32 for both of my OpenCL devices (GPUs). However, I'm running on a 64-bit machine. Is this a bug?

Comment: It's possible that the GPU or the driver only supports 32-bit addressing, so it's not necessarily a bug. You could also write a simple test kernel that runs `sizeof(image2d_t)` and `sizeof(global uchar4*)` to find out how big these arguments are. It could also be that kernel arguments are 8-byte aligned on your device.